# Does the series $\sum_n \frac{e^nn!}{n^n}$ converge or diverge?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I want to prove convergence or divergence of the series
$$\sum_n \frac{e^nn!}{n^n}.$$

My suggestion is to let $U_n = \frac{e^nn!}{n^n}$ and apply D'Alambert's test:
$$\lim_n \frac{U_{n+1}}{U_n} = \lim_n e\left({\frac{n}{n+1}}\right)^{n+1}=1$$

Is there any method? Please help.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: Yeah, Stirling's approximation  says $$n!e^n/n^n\sim \sqrt{2\pi n}.$$

Comment: Any Other Methode Not applique methode stirling's ,

Comment: The root test may work.

Comment: @SeanRoberson The root test doesn't work, the limit is $1$, so the test is inconclusive.

Comment: One need not use the ratio test since the general terms of the series do not tend to zero.  In fact, they grow like the square root of $n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $e^n =\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{n^k}{k!} > \frac{n^n}{n!}$ so $\frac{e^n n!}{n^n}>1$ for all $n$, so the series diverges.

Answer (score 2):

D'alambert's theorem actually asserts that if $a_n\neq 0$ and $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\geq 1$ for sufficiently large $n$, then the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ diverges. In your case
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{e}{(1+\frac{1}{n})^n}$$
Since the sequence $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ increases to $e$, one deduces that
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}>1$$
for all $n$, hence-- by D'alembert's full theorem -- the series diverges.